# Pinot nested json ingestion

Tags: pinot

I have this json schema

```
{
  "name":"Pete"
  "age":24,
  "subjects":[
    {
      "name":"maths"
      "grade":"A"
    },
    {
      "name":"maths"
      "grade":"B"
    }
  ]
}
```

and I want to ingest this into a pinot table to run a query like

```
select age,subjects_grade,count(*) from table group by age,subjects_grade
```

Is there a way to do this in a pinot job?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pinot has two ways to handle JSON records:

**1. Flatten the record during ingestion time**:
In this case, we treat each nested field as a separated field, so need to:

- Define those fields in the table schema
- Define transform functions to flatten nested fields in table config

Please see how column `subjects_name` and `subjects_grade` is defined below. Since it's an array, so both fields are multi-value columns in Pinot.

**2. Directly ingest JSON records**

In this case, we treat each nested field as one single field, so need to:

- Define the JSON field in table schema as a string with maxLength value
- Put this field into **noDictionaryColumns** and **jsonIndexColumns** in table config
- Define transform functions `jsonFormat` to stringify the JSON field in table config

Please see how column `subjects_str` is defined below.

Below is the sample table schema/config/query:

**Sample Pinot Schema:**

```
{
  "metricFieldSpecs": [],
  "dimensionFieldSpecs": [
    {
      "dataType": "STRING",
      "name": "name"
    },
    {
      "dataType": "LONG",
      "name": "age"
    },
    {
      "dataType": "STRING",
      "name": "subjects_str"
    },
    {
      "dataType": "STRING",
      "name": "subjects_name",
      "singleValueField": false
    },
    {
      "dataType": "STRING",
      "name": "subjects_grade",
      "singleValueField": false
    }
  ],
  "dateTimeFieldSpecs": [],
  "schemaName": "myTable"
}
```

**Sample Table Config:**

```
{
    "tableName": "myTable",
    "tableType": "OFFLINE",
    "segmentsConfig": {
        "segmentPushType": "APPEND",
        "segmentAssignmentStrategy": "BalanceNumSegmentAssignmentStrategy",
        "schemaName": "myTable",
        "replication": "1"
    },
    "tenants": {},
    "tableIndexConfig": {
        "loadMode": "MMAP",
        "invertedIndexColumns": [],
        "noDictionaryColumns": [
            "subjects_str"
        ],
        "jsonIndexColumns": [
            "subjects_str"
        ]
    },
    "metadata": {
        "customConfigs": {}
    },
    "ingestionConfig": {
        "batchIngestionConfig": {
            "segmentIngestionType": "APPEND",
            "segmentIngestionFrequency": "DAILY",
            "batchConfigMaps": [],
            "segmentNameSpec": {},
            "pushSpec": {}
        },
        "transformConfigs": [
            {
                "columnName": "subjects_str",
                "transformFunction": "jsonFormat(subjects)"
            },
            {
                "columnName": "subjects_name",
                "transformFunction": "jsonPathArray(subjects, '$.[*].name')"
            },
            {
                "columnName": "subjects_grade",
                "transformFunction": "jsonPathArray(subjects, '$.[*].grade')"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Sample Query:**

```
select age, subjects_grade, count(*) from myTable GROUP BY  age, subjects_grade
```

[image]

```
select age, json_extract_scalar(subjects_str, '$.[*].grade', 'STRING') as subjects_grade, count(*) from myTable GROUP BY  age, subjects_grade
```

[image]

Comparing both ways, we recommend solution 1 to flatten the nested fields out when the field density is high(e.g. every document has field *name* and *grade*, then it's worth extracting them out to be new columns), it gives better query performance and better storage efficiency.

For solution 2, it's simpler in configuration, and good for sparse fields(e.g. only a few documents have certain fields). It requires to use **json_extract_scalar** function to access the nested field.

Please also note the behavior of Pinot GROUP BY on multi-value columns.

More references:

[Pinot Column Transformation](https://docs.pinot.apache.org/developers/advanced/ingestion-level-transformations#column-transformation)

[Pinot JSON Functions](https://docs.pinot.apache.org/users/user-guide-query/supported-transformations#json-functions)

[Pinot JSON Index](https://docs.pinot.apache.org/basics/indexing/json-index)

[Pinot Multi-value Functions](https://docs.pinot.apache.org/users/user-guide-query/supported-aggregations#multi-value-column-functions)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Also can you point me to the documentation of jsonPathArray transform function. This page https://docs.pinot.apache.org/developers/advanced/ingestion-level-transformations#column-transformation says it TBD. I am also looking for the transformation function to extract a specific attribute.

Comment: This is a newly added function, you can try it using docker image: `apachepinot/pinot:latest` and it will be available officially from Pinot 0.7.0 release

Comment: Added the description here: https://docs.pinot.apache.org/users/user-guide-query/supported-transformations#json-functions

Comment: Thanks for the description. On off topic query, how do I configure S3 as my deep storage in kubernetes. The link on this page for they very same info is not working https://docs.pinot.apache.org/operators/tutorials/deployment-pinot-on-kubernetes

Comment: Have you seen this one: https://docs.pinot.apache.org/users/tutorials/use-s3-as-deep-store-for-pinot

Comment: Also, you can join Apache Pinot Slack for questions: https://communityinviter.com/apps/apache-pinot/apache-pinot

Comment: How can I do transformation on live ingestion ? I am getting 

The destination column 'subjects_str' of the transform function must be present in the schema, Whereas I have this column in the schema file